# Dataset from generator that yields multiple elements at a time

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm testing the waters if it's time to migrate to the Dataset API in TensorFlow from the deprecated queue-based API.

One use case I can't seem to find the equivalent for is the `enqueue_many` parameter of `tf.train.batch`.

In particular I would like to create a Python generator that can yield "batched" arrays, where the "batch size" is not necessarily the same as the one used for SGD training updates and then apply batching on that stream of data (i.e. as it is with enqueue_many in tf.train.batch).

Is there any workaround to achieve this in the new Dataset API?

Comment: Of course, you can simply yield multiple (as many) arrays at one time in your generator function - this is independent of the batch size used in SGD. You set the SGD batch size by calling the `batch` method on the corresponding dataset object.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear. I don't mean yielding different "fields", like an image a label. I mean yielding already batched collections, i.e. yielding an array of shape [N, H, W, C], containing several images. I am referring specifically to something equivalent to the enqueue_many parameter of tf.train.batch. More specifically: I want to produce several images in one go, not in multiple `yield`s. The reason for this is a bit long to explain, but it's mainly efficiency and existing infrastructure I've built using multiprocessing etc. It was really convenient to use `enqueue_many`.

Comment: Yes, that is also what I was referring to. I'm not familiar with the queue API of TF, but what you are describing is possible in the dataset API (in fact, I use it extensively).

Comment: @isarandi can you share more details on how your data stream is going to be? Off the top of my head, the [interleave](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#interleave) method of tf.data seems to be something similar to what you are looking for?

Comment: Btw, @isarandi you mention "efficiency and existing infrastructure... using multiprocessing...". As of now, the recommended method for this is still `tf.data` API as it does all of this for you. In fact, `tf.data` uses a slightly aggressive data loading strategy (can be observed by monitoring memory usage). So while I don't know your exact use case, in most cases `tf.data` will be a safer, cleaner, easier and more efficient choice.

Comment: Using TF ops to build my preprocessing pipeline is infeasible, I'm heavily relying on custom processing that would be extremely tedious with TF ops. However py_func has a problem because of the global interpreter lock and won't run in parallel. Therefore I'm wrapping over a multiprocessing pool to do my preprocessing in parallel and push the results into queues (or from now on, yield them to a dataset). My queue-based setup is very efficient and allows for near 100% GPU usage due to the buffering and parallelization. Hope I can achieve the same with tf.data.

Answer (score 1):

Try using flatmap

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
n_reads=10
read_batch_size=20
training_batch_size = 2

def mnist_gen():
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)
    for i in range(n_reads):
        batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(read_batch_size)
        # Yielding a batch instead of single record
        yield batch_x,batch_y
data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(mnist_gen,output_types=(tf.float32,tf.float32))
data = data.flat_map(lambda *x: tf.data.Dataset.zip(tuple(map(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices,x)))).batch(training_batch_size)
# if u yield only batch_x change lambda function to data.flat_map(lambda x: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x)))
iter = data.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_item = iter.get_next()

X= next_item[0]
Y = next_item[1]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(n_reads*read_batch_size // training_batch_size):
        print(i, sess.run(X))
```